# Open an application from other application and press one of its button in Android

Tags: android

I want to open an application from my app and then press one of its button as it opens.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know the package name of the application, You can use the following code below

```
  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
  startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: and what about pressing any button in that application as it opens?

Comment: I did not get your question

Comment: what about pressing button of launched application programmaticly  ?

Comment: i want to open the application and then press any of its button by code first as it opens! did this cleared things?

Comment: You want to simulate the click of a button on an external application? If so, you cant.

Comment: You cannot do it as far as i know

Comment: Not unless the application you open uses intent parameters to perform actions. But if you have **not** created the application you are opening, you have no way of knowing if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

[Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android) to start the other application
you can then pass data in the intent such as

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);

intent.launchIntent("PushButtonId", buttonId);
startActivity(intent)
```

Then retrieve datas int the started app

```
String text = myIntent.getStringExtra("PushButtonId");
```

Comment: This will only work if you have access to the source code of the application that is to be opened, and know that the intent will be used to perform an action. This is _not_ a general solution to the question as one does not exist.

Comment: yes you are right, i may have made too many assumption from this short answer.